# Definition of conductivity: Derivative or Ratio of $V$-$I$-curve?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

I was wondering if the conduvtivity $\sigma\propto dI/dV$ or $\propto I/V$ where $I$ is the current and $V$ the voltage?

Comment: Well, what does Ohm's law say?

Comment: Imagine a perfectly conductive piece of wire and a resistor, one has a voltage drop across it and one does not... mind you it is the **voltage drop** you are looking for, for a perfectly conductive material there should be no difference "before" and "after" it

Comment: @Qmechanic Isn't that the question OP is asking? This is a question about what is the definition. You typically cant logic your way into knowing a definition.

Answer (score 0):

For nonlinear relations that are linearized over suitably small ranges (such as Ohm's Law and Hooke's Law), the relevant system property (conductivity and stiffness, respectively) can be estimated from *either* the **secant** or **chord** ($I/V$ or $\Delta I/\Delta V$ for Ohm's Law) or the **tangent** ($dI/dV$). For clarity, one should note the method used, as the two methods generally yield different estimates in the absence of linearity.

See also "[What is the difference between transresistance and differential resistance?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/467738/what-is-the-difference-between-transresistance-and-differential-resistance)" for a discussion specific to electronics.

Comment: @Lighter, just check what is IV curve of a Schottky diode (rising resistance) or a Josephson junction (negative resistance). The definition of resistance depends on the nature of a specific device in question.